# Go Tour #18: understanding pic.Show

Tags: function, go

I did not understand how the function call `pic.Show(Pic)` works and what it does.

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    pic := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for y := range pic {
        pic[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x := range pic[y] {
            pic[y][x] = uint8(5 * (x + y))
        }
    }
    return pic
}

func main() {
    //pic.Show(Pic(40,30)) // doesn't work, but why?
    pic.Show(Pic) // works, but why? Where are the values for dx and dy set?
}
```

There is, starting at line 5, a function, named `Pic`, and it receives two integer variables (`dx`, `dy`). So I think, a correct function call might be `Pic(40,30)` (with `40` and `30` being the values for `dx` and `dy`).

- But why does line 17 throw an error? (`pic.Show(Pic(40,30))`)
- Why does line line 18 work? (`pic.Show(Pic)`)
- And where do the values of `dx` and `dy` come from when line 18 is executed?

I tried to look up http://golang.org/x/tour/pic which redirects me to https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tour/pic. There I can read, that the function `Show` is defined this way:

```
func Show(f func(int, int) [][]uint8)
```

Which I understand as:

> `Show` is a function that needs one parameter. This parameter is a function that needs two parameters, both of type `int`, and it has to return a value of type `[][]uint8` (a slice of slices of unsigned 8-bit integers). `Show` itself doesn't return anything.

So, here again, I read that the inner function (the parameter of `Show`) needs two parameters. But why do I get an error, when I try to provide those parameters? Why is it ok to call the function Pic without parameters? And where do the values for those parameters come from, when Pic is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `Pic(40, 30)` you call the function `Pic` and it returns a `[][]uint8` (as seen in the function definition). This means that in your commented-out code you pass a `[][]uint8` to `Show`.

When you say `Show(Pic)` you pass `Pic` as the parameter, which is a function. That is what `Show` expects. `Pic` is of type `func(dx, dy int) [][]uint8`.

Go allows you to pass functions around as parameters and that is what is happening here.

Comment: Ok. But where do the values for dx and dy come from? How can I send my own width and height to this function?

Comment: The implementation of `Show` will call the function that you give it internally. The thing you write in the example is `Pic` which returns a picture (as a 2D array of gray values). `Show` is now given this "image generator" to show its results. `Show` will call `Pic`, or any other image generator function that you pass it, and it knows how to display `Pic`'s resulting gray image. Thus the name `Show`.

Comment: I've got it now. This is explained later in this tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/24 I think it would be wise not to use templates in an exercise that are left unexplained until this point.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right about definition of `Show` - it is a function which accepts another specific format notion as a parameter. 
`Pic` is such a function matching this criteria  - so you pass it to `Show` successfully.

But when you call `Pic(30,40)` that means not a function but a *result* of calling the function with such parameters.  So in this case you passs to `Show` not a function `Pic` but a slice returned by it `[][]uint8`. Of course Show can’t accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function, `Pic`, takes two parameters, `Show` takes one. You're calling `Show` with a single parameter, which is a function; that function takes two parameters. When you pass a function to another function, the assumption is that the function you're calling (`Show`) will call the function you passed in (`Pic`) and provide the necessary parameters when it makes that call.

Comment: Click the headlines on godoc.org to see the code implementing the thing that is being documented. `Pic` (the function you pass to `Show`) is called [right here](https://github.com/golang/tour/blob/27c87204043c53a016e3b3282daebaf756e484aa/pic/pic.go#L20).